# Sync music tags to PC

Tags: sync, linux, music

My music library is located in my PC, and it is copied to my phone SD using the media player I use in the PC.
Now, I listen to music mostly out of home, using the phone. I think it is safer to keep the music library master in the PC (I can lose my phone or it can be stolen). It often happens that I find a song which tags (ID3 for instance) need to be edited/corrected.

Is there a way to correct them and ensure the music in the PC is synced later?
I would like to get a solution which operates on the player level. For example, I would like to edit tags while listening to music in the phone, that would sync later on with my PC.

I use Ubuntu in my PC, with Rhythmbox player. Anyway I am open to alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to alternative ways of syncing, you might want to take a look at e.g. [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite):

[image: FolderSync] [image: FolderSync folder pairs]

It enables you to sync selected locations with different cloud services, but also with your local "home network". You can set it to automatically synchronize, or have it done manually on-demand.

For your issue, you could set either the base directory of your music to completely synchronize between your Android device and your PC, or chose selected directories. So when you updated some tags, only those files should be "copied to the other side", as the others have not changed. Same applies if you add new music files.

There are some other apps in the playstore doing the same job, just in case you want some alternatives. One of them would be [FTPSyncX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syncoorp.FTPSyncX_Trial) which, other than its name suggests, also handles different protocols (Samba/Windows Shares, SFTP/SSH, FTPS).

Comment: Thank you Izzy, my real question is regarding any possible solution which operates on the player level. For example, I would like to edit tags while listening to music in the phone, that would sync later on with my PC. I will precise the question.

Comment: Isn't that what my answer offers? Edit tags with whatever app, the `.mp3` gets written back to the file system. So on the next sync interval/event, the sync app detects the changed files and syncs them to your PC. As the tags (if we talk about mp3-tags, that is) are written to the `.mp3` files, the changes then show up on the PC as well. Trouble only arises when editing the same file on both ends at the same time...

Comment: I think that using a 'general' sync tool would not work. If I were listening to a song and I decided to edit its tags, I would have to 1: close the player; 2: open a separate tag editor; 3: restart the player. I would like a solution I could edit tags directly from the Android player.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments on [Izzy's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/33618/156) it seems that what you're actually asking for is a way to edit the MP3's ID3 tag from within your music player, without having to switch between apps. Once that's sorted out any file sync app (as suggested in Izzy's answer) would work for you.

There's not many music players on Android that allow you to edit the tags within the player, the best recommended one for that seems to be [PowerAmp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) (paid app with 15 day trial).